# ML model for machine failure prediction

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, time-series, prediction, anomaly-detection

I want to develop an ML model to predict machine failure prior failure. I have a time series dataset from various sensors(10 sensors) of machine. In this dataset we have 10 days dataset before each failure.
How do i start by using Machine learning model and python.

I wants this model will predict the failure 1 day before the failure.
Please help.
Thanks You.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest you some resources about **predictive maintenance** (which is exactly predicting "machine failure prior failure"). [This source](https://medium.com/bigdatarepublic/machine-learning-for-predictive-maintenance-where-to-start-5f3b7586acfb) should be adapted to get started.

Then, you may want to learn about **survival analysis** and especially **Weibull distributions** that can be adapted to your modeling. This is a usual way to represent the time to failure of a component. You can find many resources online about Weibull models, more or less technical, along with implementations in Python or R. For a deep learning approach, you can consult [this source](https://medium.com/data-science-vademecum/deep-time-to-failure-predictive-maintenance-and-survival-analysis-using-rnns-and-weibull-f54af3ef8056).